# get access to array build with pluck function in laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel

this is the query

```
        $gg = DB::table('member_opinions')->where('user_id',$id)->pluck('committees_opinion');
```

result of dd($gg);

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1436
  #items: array:2 [
    0 => "مؤهل"
    1 => "غير مؤهل"
  ]
}
```

and I want to compare the values in loop in the controller

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: How can I compare the values of this array

Comment: Compare for what? Alphabetic order? Length? Lexigraphic index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `each` method iterates over the items in the collection and passes each item to a closure. Here you can compare the values.

```
$gg->each(function ($item, $key) {
    //
});
```

More collections method is also present. Link for ref - https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections